# Kotlin: How to parse Avro message to Json or data class

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to set up a service that consumes Kafka topics. I am stuck at current part.

When topic is consumed I get back something like:

```
�{"id": "df7c4bb5-dc19-40f2-9f0a-77956c15be15", "dob": "1924-12-07", "last_name": "Doe", "first_name": "John",} created
```

which I think is Avro format I presume

Now, any idea how this can be parsed? I would love to have some type of data class or class in general defined as:

```
    val id: String,
    val first_name: String,
    val last_name: String,
    ...

)
```

And map that value to it. Tried some libs, but couldn't quite make it to work. Thoughts, examples?

Comment: What exactly did you try? What didn't work? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the leading character, it looks like Avro, yes, however it might be simply be an Avro string type rather than an object with individual fields...

In any case, if you use the [Avro maven plugin](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/gettingstartedjava.html) (there's a different plugin for Gradle) and define a schema matching the record (seems like you might be using a Schema Registry, so you can get the schema from there), then Maven will build a matching Java class for you (`mvn compile`) to use from Kotlin.

Upon consuming the data with an appropriate AvroDeserializer class, your record will be deserialized to that type